# How do I populate auto generated input fields with Vue / Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have only been doing `Vue` for 2 weeks, it's going well and all seems to make sense but I can't get my head around the following.

I am generating a set of **select inputs** based on **options** stored in the **database** for `user` preferences. And the `user` in some cases will already have selected options for some or all of them.

The problem I am having is I can't get the generated **select inputs** to pre-populate with the users current selections.

I had it populating right up until I was auto-generating the inputs. Here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need any more information please let me know. I think it is fairly obvious what I am trying to do, and it just seems the Vue code overwrites the values and makes them blank on generation.

Code in the `blade.php`

```
<div class="form-group row" v-for="preference in preferences">
   <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
       @{{ preference.name }}
       <span v-if="currentPreferences[preference.id] && currentPreferences[preference.id].value">
            <br /> (current: @{{ currentPreferences[preference.id].value }})
       </span>
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <select class="form-control" @change="updatePreferences(preference)" v-model="selected[preference.id]">
         <template v-if="currentPreferences[preference.id] && currentPreferences[preference.id].value">
            <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
            <option v-for="item in preference.options" :value="item" :selected="item == currentPreferences[preference.id].value">@{{ item }}</option>
         </template>
         <template v-else>
            <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
            <option v-for="item in preference.options" :value="item">@{{ item }}</option>
         </template>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Code in `hero-preferences.js`

```
Vue.component('dashboard-preferences', {
    props: ['user'],

    data() {
        return {
            preferences: [],
            currentPreferences: []
        };
    },

    mounted() {
        this.getPreferencesData();
    },

    methods: {
        getPreferences() {
            axios.get('/dashboard/preferences')
                .then(response => {
                    this.preferences = JSON.parse(response.data);
                })
                .catch(response => {
                    this.preferences = [];
                });
        },
        getCurrentPreferences() {
            axios.get('/dashboard/preferences/current')
                .then(response => {
                    this.currentPreferences = JSON.parse(response.data);
                })
                .catch(response => {
                    this.currentPreferences = [];
                });
        },
        getPreferencesData() {
            this.getPreferences();
            this.getCurrentPreferences();
        }
    }
});
```

Code in `email-preferences.js` (sub-component)

```
Vue.component('dashboard-hero-preferences-email-preferences', {
    props: ['user','preferences','currentPreferences'],

    data() {
        return {
            updated: null,
            selected: [],
            updatePreference: null
        };
    },

    methods: {
        updatePreferences(preference) {
            this.updatePreference = preference;

            axios.post('/dashboard/preferences/update', {
                preference: preference.id,
                value: this.selected[preference.id]
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.$emit('update');
                this.updated = 'yes';
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you, David

Comment: You are binding the `selected`  data prop to the select dropdown. If you want to pre-seed that you should do so in a `mounted` statement of the component.

Comment: @Luceos The problem is the inputs are auto generated so unsure how to mount them. When it was static it was pre-filling fine. But now I can't figure out how to assign them. Unless I loop through and try and fix them to the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by adding the following mounted method to email-preferences.js, thanks to @luceos above for the input.

```
mounted() {
        var items = null;
        axios.get('/dashboard/preferences/current').then((response) => {
            items = JSON.parse(response.data);

            Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
                this.selected[key] = items[key].value;
            })
        })
    },
```